How to calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}(a+\sin{x})^{-3/2}dx$
I wonder if there is an analytic solution for the following equation:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}(a+\sin{x})^{-3/2}dx$$
Here, $a$ is a constant.
Would you please give an advice?

It's not a equation!  $$\frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{a}{a+1}} \left(E\left(\frac{\pi }{4}|\frac{2}{a+1}\right)+E\left(\frac{3 \pi }{4}|\frac{2}{a+1}\right)\right)}{(a-1)
\sqrt{a}}$$ for a>1. where: $E$ is elliptic integral of the second kind.

Does this answer your question? How to evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin^2\theta+a)^{-3/2},d\theta$, where $a>0$
